# PDF DRM Print only once

Tags: php, pdf, drm

I am looking to create an online gift certificate and sell these via paypal on a website for a restaurant.

The website is Wordpress / PHP based and will be using Gravity Forms / PayPal addon to capture the users details and take payment for the gift certificate.

I can create a PDF certificate which the customer will be able to redeem by printing and visiting the restaurant.

Now the problem lies with management of the gift certificates. e.g. what is to stop a customer printing off a gift certificate and redeeming it. Then next time they visit the restaurant, printing off the certificate again.

RoyalMail.com has some kind of DRM solution whereby online postage can be printed off once and only once.

How can I programatically protect my PDF files to only allow them to be downloaded / printed once?

For the sake of clarification, I do not want to know whether this is a good idea or not. I know that it is not an ideal solution. All I want to know is how to do it/if it is possible. No solution is fool proof, and people will always be able to 'forge' or duplicate the certificates. I just want to mitigate the possibility of doing so. Naturally there will be an in-house mechanism for checking redeemed certificates.

With regards to comment about spilling coffee on the certificate... AFAIK, if you put cash into the washing machine with your clothes, you have to ask the bank of england to re-issue you the bank note. You cannot re-print your own bank note!

Comment: This has been discussed here: http://superuser.com/questions/37216/restrict-print-copies-on-a-pdf
Basically, it is a bad idea. There are a million reasons against DRM. Plus everybody has learned to "print" into a new PDF file now. And what about old school photocopies? You should rather fix your voucher system to have unique serial numbers or similar.

Comment: I agree with your opinion, but I still want to know how to do this please.

Comment: A PDF is just a file. It can not control itself, e.g. restrict itself by only being copied once. You're probably looking for one of these devices from the movies that destroy itself after they have played once (and then always this cool music plays, I mean that's something!).

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing to stop a user printing off as many copies of a certificate as they want.  But managing the certificates based on their physical copies is a really really bad idea anyway.  If someone prints out a coupon and then spills their coffee all over it then do they have to buy another one?  And what's to stop someone printing off their single copy and then running that through a photocopier?

If each voucher has a unique ID encoded in it, then all you have to do is record the fact that the voucher has been redeemed.  Then it doesn't matter how many physical copies there are, if a voucher has already been redeemed once then you know not to redeem it again if someone else presents you with the same voucher.

Comment: Each voucher will have unique identifier anyway. We have inhouse methods to check whether the voucher has been redeemed or not. I would still like to be able to add this extra layer of protection.

Comment: a) it's no protection at all for the reasons I've already described, and b) it's unnecessary if you're already checking the voucher's identifier.